# How to restart iteration with Map.values() method?

Tags: javascript, typescript, iteration

I want to restart iteration after the iterator reaches to done state.
Just look at the example:

```
const newMap = new Map<string, string>([
  ['key1', 'value1'],
  ['key2', 'value2']
]);

const iterator = newMap.values() // It can be newMap.entries()

iterator.next().value   // prints value1
iterator.next().value    //prints value2
iterator.next().value //prints undefined
```

I just want something like:

```
iterator.restart();
iterator.next().value // prints value1
```

Comment: You can call `newMap.values()` again. Does that suffice?

Comment: I was thinking about just sharing one single property along with other services and just controlling the flow with that but it seems there is no way to restart and reuse that.

maybe there are better solutions for the problem. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want endlessly repeating values, you can make a generator function that caches the values the first time around and then keeps giving you the cached from the start forever:

```js
function* repeat(iterable) {
  const cache = [];
  
  //lazily supply the values from the iterable while caching them
  for (const next of iterable) {
    cache.push(next);
    yield next;
  }
  
  //delegate to the cache at this point
  while(true)
    yield* cache;
}

const newMap = new Map([
  ['key1', 'value1'],
  ['key2', 'value2']
]);

const iterator = repeat(newMap.values()) // It can be newMap.entries()

console.log(iterator.next().value) // prints value1
console.log(iterator.next().value) // prints value2
console.log(iterator.next().value) // prints value1
console.log(iterator.next().value) // prints value2
console.log(iterator.next().value) // prints value1
console.log(iterator.next().value) // prints value2
```

Alternatively, if you do not want to cache, you can make the `repeat()` implementation simpler by taking a function which gives you an iterable. Any time you call it, you get a new one and delegate to it forever:

```js
function* repeat(iterableSupplier) {
  //delegate to the value from the supplier
  while(true)
    yield* iterableSupplier();
}

const newMap = new Map([
  ['key1', 'value1'],
  ['key2', 'value2']
]);

const iterator = repeat(() => newMap.values()) // It can be newMap.entries()
//    give a function   ^^^^^

console.log(iterator.next().value) // prints value1
console.log(iterator.next().value) // prints value2
console.log(iterator.next().value) // prints value1
console.log(iterator.next().value) // prints value2
console.log(iterator.next().value) // prints value1
console.log(iterator.next().value) // prints value2
```

See more about:

- [`function*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) - generator functions
- [`yield*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*) - delegating to to another iterable
- [Iterators and generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators) - about more on the topic in general

Answer (score 2):

Call `.values` (or whatever method it was) again.

```js
const newMap = new Map([
  ['key1', 'value1'],
  ['key2', 'value2']
]);

let iterator = newMap.values() // It can be newMap.entries()

console.log(iterator.next().value)   // prints value1
console.log(iterator.next().value)    //prints value2
console.log(iterator.next().value) //prints undefined

iterator = newMap.values()
console.log(iterator.next().value) // prints value1
```

Iterators aren't reusable - you have to create them anew every time you want to start from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

You could craft your own iterator that, when asked to, calls newMap.values() again:

```js
const newMap = new Map([
  ['key1', 'value1'],
  ['key2', 'value2']
]);

const myIterator = (() => {
  let currentIterator = newMap.values();
  
  return {
    next() {
      return currentIterator.next();
    },
    restart() {
      currentIterator = newMap.values();
    }
  }
})()
console.log(myIterator.next().value)   // prints value1
console.log(myIterator.next().value)    //prints value2
console.log(myIterator.next().value) //prints undefined

myIterator.restart();
console.log(myIterator.next().value) // prints value1
```