# What is the Python itertools cycle equivalent in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, python-itertools, cycle

I could not find an equivalent function of Python cycle in itertools:

```
from itertools import cycle
g = cycle(('a','b'))
next(g) # a
next(g) # b
next(g) # a
# etc. etc.
```

in Javascript.

The goal is to create an infinite cycle in an array of values. I guess I could use a Javascript generator but I was wondering if there is any built-in function.

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of a [generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator?

Comment: @evolutionxbox thanks but as I wrote in the question, I am aware of generators, the question is if there is a built-in function to perform this task. The generator to be built is quite complex so I would like to see if there are built-in atlernatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built in functionality for this. With that said, it is easy to make a function that accepts any  number of arguments and cycles through them:

```js
function* cycle(...items) {
  while(true)
    yield* items;
}


const gen = cycle("a", "b");

console.log(gen.next().value);
console.log(gen.next().value);
console.log(gen.next().value);
```

This uses [`yield*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*) to delegate to the iterator of the array `items`, effectively `yield* items;` is a shorter version of

```
for (const item of items)
  yield item;
```

Alternatively, it can accept an array and continually cycle through its contents

```js
function* cycle(items) {
  while(true)
    yield* items;
}


const gen = cycle(["a", "b"]);

console.log(gen.next().value);
console.log(gen.next().value);
console.log(gen.next().value);
```

If it has to support any iterables passed in, it will have to maintain a chache of the first iteration, so it can repeat the further cycles. I have shown an implementation of this [in this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71532196). Here is the implementation:

```js
function* repeat(iterable) {
  const cache = [];
  
  //lazily supply the values from the iterable while caching them
  for (const next of iterable) {
    cache.push(next);
    yield next;
  }
  
  //delegate to the cache at this point
  while(true)
    yield* cache;
}

const newMap = new Map([
  ['key1', 'value1'],
  ['key2', 'value2']
]);

const iterator = repeat(newMap.values()) // It can be newMap.entries()

console.log(iterator.next().value) // prints value1
console.log(iterator.next().value) // prints value2
console.log(iterator.next().value) // prints value1
console.log(iterator.next().value) // prints value2
console.log(iterator.next().value) // prints value1
console.log(iterator.next().value) // prints value2
```

---

There is a proposal called [Iterator helpers](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-iterator-helpers) which aims to add tools similar to itertools and, in general, ease the use of iterators. The proposal is currently in stage 2 out of 4 in the approval process.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is the answer I was looking for. I just can't find what is the asterisk used for in the documentation. Could you please elaborate on its usage? It seems that is the key to creating the cycle.

Comment: It's the link I put before the first code block: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield* I probably should have made it more prominent. `yield*` will delegate to another iterator